# images moving side to side when window is scaled

Tags: jquery, html, css

So as the title says,  when I scale the page out of fullscreen I noticed the background divs scale but the Images move up and down and don't scale down to stay inside of the background div/wrapper div they just kinda overlap each other.  How would I get them to move with their div?

Also, I'm going to be using jquery to remove the images when the user is on a phone or tablet, then shift the background divs to go width-ways. I only know how to remove images with jQuery in CSS, so is there a way to move the images to the CSS file?

Also Also, pointers on cleaning up my code are more than welcome.

```css
 
html, body{
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;

    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;

    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}


body{
 background: #4a525e;
 max-height: 950px;
 font-family: Barrio;

}
div{
 margin: auto;
}
#container{
 padding-bottom: 0;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}

.wrapper{
 image-rendering: auto;

}

.beastboy{
 background: #84C303;
 width: 20%;
 height: 950px;
 float: left;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}
.beastboy img{
 image-rendering: auto;
 padding-top: 75%;
 margin: auto;
}

.starfire{
 background: #AC9C01;
 width: 20%; 
html, body{
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;

    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;

    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}


body{
 background: #4a525e;
 max-height: 950px;
 font-family: Barrio;

}
div{
 margin: auto;
}
#container{
 padding-bottom: 0;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}

.wrapper{
 image-rendering: auto;

}

.beastboy{
 background: #84C303;
 width: 20%;
 height: 950px;
 float: left;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}
.beastboy img{
 image-rendering: auto;
 padding-top: 75%;
 margin: auto;
}
.starfire{
 background: #AC9C01;
 width: 20%;
 height: 950px;
 float: left;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}
.starfire img{
 padding-top: 15%;
 padding-left: -50px;

}
```

```html
   <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="beastboy">
      <a href="beastboy.html">
       <img class="beastboyimg" src="img/BeastBoyOurline.png">
      </a>   
   </div>
  
   </div>

  
   <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="starfire">
      <div class="starfireImg"></div>
      <img src="img/StarfireOutline.png">
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: First, your CSS seems to be doubled, could you update that part so we have how it suppose be

Comment: + also add working images

Comment: Images you mentioned is on local path, Please update you HTML with CDN path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your css, the image will scale down to fit on the container.

```
img {
  max-width:100%
}
```